# Improving the Performance for inserting elements into Linked List from an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to insert the elements of an array into Linked List. The following is the piece of code that I am using:

```
for (int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
    {
        Node* n1 = new Node();
        n1->SetData(randArray[i]);
        n1->SetIndex(i);
        n1->SetNext(NULL);

        //checks if NULL
        if (start == NULL) {
            start = n1;
            start->SetNext(NULL);
        }
        else {
            //inserts the values to the end of the node
            Node *p = start;
            while (p->GetNext() != NULL) {
                p = p->GetNext();
            }
            p->SetNext(n1);
        }
    }
```

Here randArray[i] consists the elements say 100000 elements.

Now I want this process to be executed faster. At present it is taking 13 seconds for 50000 elements.

Can someone help out in this?

Comment: Seems like nobody mentioned memory pools and custom allocators.

Comment: @ddriver a user did recommend memory pools, but then removed their comment. I'm guessing those things would be out of scope of what Vamsi is looking for, even though they could be useful for other people who do have an algorithmically sound program but still need it to be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're now looking for the last node every time you insert a new node... but you would already know where the last node is because you just inserted it in the last iteration - if only you hadn't thrown that information away. Simply keep a pointer to it stored in a variable that isn't destroyed at the end of the iteration. Another way - which is a bit more typical for singly linked lists - is to only insert at the front of the list. If you want the elements in the same order as in the array, then iterate the array in reverse order.

Getting rid of the linear search for end reduces your algorithm's runtime complexity from O(n^2) to O(n).

Another optimization that will have less impact on performance, but will make your code simpler: Use the insert-in-front-only-approach and implement your list using a sentinel node. That way you don't need a branch in every iteration. That said, the branch probably has little effect due to being easily predictable. You can get rid of the branch with the remember-last-node approach too, by moving the test outside of loop, but that won't simplify your code.

EDIT: sentinel node is not needed after all, even though it does simplify some other list algorithms. I was bored, so I implemented the insert-in-front-only approach:

```
Node* head = nullptr;
for (size_t i = MAXSIZE; i --> 0;) {
    Node* n = new Node();
    n->SetData(randArray[i]);
    n->SetIndex(i); // †
    n->SetNext(head);
    head = n;
}
```

† You may want to reconsider if you really want to store the index in a node. Updating it when nodes are later inserted or removed from anywhere else other than the tail is going to be quite slow.

Comment: Hi I understood your answer theoretically but how can I implement that in my code. Can you please show that. I am kind of new to linkedlist topics

Comment: @Vamsi show us how you tried to implement it and we can tell you what went wrong. That said, m_pOatrix just posted an implementation for you.

Comment: @user2079303 - your answer shows nodes being inserted to the beginning of the list, but the question example code is appending nodes to the end of a list, which is normally done using a pointer to the last node of a list.

Comment: @rcgldr You don't usually ever insert at the end of a singly linked list, but it's of course possible by storing a pointer to the node in a variable. As I've explained in my answer, Vamsi can do it either way. The order in which nodes are inserted is irrelevant, as long as the nodes are in the correct order after the insertion. I iterate the array in reverse, so the the result is the same but the code is much simpler.

Comment: @rcgldr `forward_list::end` doesn't return the last element. It returns iterator to one past the last element (i.e. what the last element points to), just like `end` of any other standard container. You can only insert *after* an element in singly linked list and trying to insert after `forward_list::end` is going to be a disaster. What you want to do is to insert after the node *before* `end`. If you want to insert or splice at the end of `forward_list`, you need to track the tail yourself. The tail is not stored in the `forward_list` instance.

Comment: @rcgldr I shall leave mine in case someone is wondering about the same thing and stumbles across. And true, there are many situations where the tail is useful and list implementations for specific purpose will keep track of it. Not all use cases do need it however, which is why a generic singly linked list typically doesn't keep track of it. At least in the case of languages that care about performance.

Comment: Why are you setting head at the next of node it will reverse the array.

Comment: @Avi because when nodes are inserted only at the head, there is no need to update a tail pointer at every iteration, which saves time. That's the way singly linked lists are typically used. The reversing is OK, because the array elements are added to the front in reverse order. Two reverses cancel out each other and the list ends up being in the same order as the array.

Comment: I accept two reverse cancel out each other but if you set node in next of head then it will also work same and the linked list will be not reversed in such case.

Comment: @Avi but that's not what my algorithm does. It doesn't set the next of the head to point to node. It sets the next of node to point to the head. And then sets the head to point to node. In other words, I insert a node to the front and the new node becomes the new head and points to the node that used to be the head.

Answer (score 2):

Applying user2079303 advice,

You should have something like that:

```
Node *p = start;
for (int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
{
    Node* n1 = new Node();
    n1->SetData(randArray[i]);
    n1->SetIndex(i);
    n1->SetNext(NULL);

    //checks if NULL
    if (start == NULL) 
    {
        start = n1;
        start->SetNext(NULL);
        p = start;
    }
    else 
    {
        //inserts the values to the end of the node
        p->SetNext(n1);
        p = p->GetNext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is example was done in case you want an actual append operation. The get and set functions prevent you from using a pointer to pointer, but this just requires one if statement to check for an empty list.

```
    Node* tail;  // pointer to last node on list (if start != NULL)
    for (int i = 0; i<MAXSIZE; i++)
    {
        Node* n1 = new Node();
        n1->SetData(randArray[i]);
        n1->SetIndex(i);

        //checks if empty list
        if (start == NULL) {
            start = n1;
            tail = n1;
        }
        else {
            tail->SetNext(n1);
            tail = tail->GetNext();
        }
    }
    tail->SetNext(NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to iterate on linked list every time if you want to add at last position you just keep hold the reference of last node and it will add the node on its next. Like:-

```
 Node* head ;
    Node* last= null;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++) {

        Node* n1 = new Node();
        n1->SetData(randArray[i]);
        n1->SetIndex(i);
        n1->SetNext(null);
        if(last != null){
             last->SetNext(n1);
        }else{
           head = n1;
        }
        last = n;
    }
```

Comment: You never set anything to point to the first node that you create. How would you use this list afterwards?

Comment: Please look at the code again may be you are not understanding it properly.

Comment: I've taken a good look at it and nowhere do you set a pointer to the first node that you create, anywhere. The only pointer that you're left with after the algorithm is `last`. You cannot reach any of the other nodes from `last` so they appear to be entirely unreachable. It seems to me that you've leaked the rest of the nodes. I ask you again, how would you use the list?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake I got your point now and corrected the code.